# Transform JDBC return values

Tags: clojure

After making a select supposed, the clojure.java.jdbc returns me something like this:

```
({:name "John"} {:name "Julia"} {:name "Alex"})
```

I need to transform this return into a vector, to look like this:

```
["John" "Julia" "Alex"]
```

How can I do this? I can't think of a way to make this transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data in the exact shape you described:

- You can use keywords as functions to extract that exact value from a map
- You can use the function `mapv` to call a function on each element of a sequence and get a vector back (eagerly)

E.g.

```
user=> (mapv :name '({:name "John"} {:name "Julia"} {:name "Alex"}))
["John" "Julia" "Alex"]
```

Comment: Thank you! It was what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
(def data [{:name "John"} {:name "Julia"} {:name "Alex"}])
(mapv :name data)
;=> ["John" "Julia" "Alex"]
```

Please see also [this list of documentation resources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

Comment: OPs example is broken in the first place. Then hhis lacks a `first` or assuming that OP has a list of maps, a `map`. Also depending on the real problem OP faces, `vals` can be dangerous due to maps not having an order.

Comment: It was really broken, I updated it, thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: Corrected to match updated question (I typed too fast w/o running it the first time!)